# is there a built in functionality in php to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss

Tags: php, time

is there a built in functionality in php to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss

Comment: None that I know of.  There are simple code snippets out there though for this. Google "php seconds to hh mm ss". First result

Comment: seconds?? do you mean timestamp??

Comment: @simshaun - I know - thanks, that's why I asked for built in.
@shankhan - seconds, not time stamps

Comment: ? why the down votes? who and how I offended with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $seconds=3672;
    echo date_create()->add(new DateInterval("PT{$seconds}S"))
                      ->diff(new DateTime)
                      ->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Just another way that works.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built in function, this will work though:

```
function formatSeconds($seconds){
  $hours = $seconds / (60 * 60);
  $minutes = ( $seconds - $hours * 60 * 60) / 60;
  $seconds = $seconds - $hours * 60 * 60 - $minutes * 60 - $seconds;
  return $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
}
```

Comment: If you want the numbers prefixed with 0's use `str_pad`.

Comment: To prefix zeros you may also use `sprintf()`. `return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);`

Comment: Thanks Amil, that's a much better solution.

Answer (score -1):

I needed an answer to this recently and I ran across [this web page](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql) concerning inserting a phpdate into a mysql table.  (I bet this is also what you're dealing with.)  It seems to indicate that you can use something like

```
$mysqldate = date( 'H:i:s', time());
```

This seems to work fine even if the number of seconds exceeds a 24 hour period.

Answer (score -2):

Yes,  the strftime() function ([manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)):

```
print(strftime("%H:%M:%S", $_seconds_ ))
```

Comment: This'll break if the number of seconds exceeds 24 hours.